# How to decrypt the NSF file

Tags: encryption, lotus-notes

I have a NSF file which I want to decrypt so that it can be opened without password.
I have changed the encryption settings of the database to "Do not locally encrypt this database". Now I need to locally replicate this database, so that the new replica would be opened without password. Please let me know the correct procedure to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To access the NSF file through the Notes client the user will have to authenticate using a local ID file - regardless of whether NSF encryption is used.

The user will be asked for a password as soon as the client is opened, in this case when the user opens the NSF file.
To avoid the user being asked for a password, you can do one of the following:

- Make sure the Notes client is already open, and a user logged in.
- Use a user ID with a blank password.
- Setup some kind of SSO, for example by using the same password used for Windows.

Bear in mind that IF the NSF file is encrypted, it should be encrypted using the same ID file later used to open it.

Answer (score 0):

After setting "Do not locally encrypt this database" you only need to **compact** the database. Then the database is not encrypted with user's Notes-id anymore and others can open the database locally too.

You can compact your database right in Notes Client workspace:

1. Select the database
2. Choose File - Database - Properties
3. Click the "Info" tab.
4. Click button "Compact"

Comment: Yes Thanks. I followed exactly the same steps, but still it is asking the ID.

Comment: "Do not locally encrypt this database" means that any Notes id is able to open the database locally as it is not encrypted anymore **but** you still have to log in with a Notes id when you open Notes client.